# GROUP BY and COUNT in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct, aggregate-functions

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all, 
       posts.id as post_id 
FROM posts 
  INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
GROUP BY posts.id;
```

Returns `n` records in Postgresql:

```
 count_all | post_id
-----------+---------
 1         | 6
 3         | 4
 3         | 5
 3         | 1
 1         | 9
 1         | 10
(6 rows)
```

I just want to retrieve the number of records returned: `6`.

I used a subquery to achieve what I want, but this doesn't seem optimum:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all, posts.id as post_id 
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
    GROUP BY posts.id
) as x;
```

How would I get the number of records in this context right in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why would you think it's not optimum?

Comment: This would seem like an operation so common there would be an easier way.

Comment: does `SELECT COUNT(*) from POSTS` work in your case?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think you just need `COUNT(DISTINCT post_id) FROM votes`.

See "4.2.7. Aggregate Expressions" section in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES.

EDIT: Corrected my careless mistake per Erwin's comment.

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @skinkelynet: that's because the answer is subtly wrong - it has to be `FROM votes`. I added the correct form to my answer.

Comment: @LostCrotchet It turns out you can do that in PostgreSQL. You need to put the list of fields in parentheses, so for example… `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (firstname, lastname)) FROM people`.

Answer (score 52):

There is also [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html):

```
SELECT count(*) AS post_ct
FROM   posts p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM votes v WHERE v.post_id = p.id);
```

In Postgres and with multiple entries on the *n*-side like you probably have, it's generally *faster* than [`count(DISTINCT post_id)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT p.id) AS post_ct
FROM   posts p
JOIN   votes v ON v.post_id = p.id;
```

The more rows per post there are in `votes`, the bigger the difference in performance. Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

`count(DISTINCT post_id)` has to read *all* rows, sort or hash them, and then only consider the first per identical set. `EXISTS` will only scan `votes` (or, preferably, an index on `post_id`) until the first match is found.

**If** every `post_id` in `votes` is guaranteed to be present in the table `posts` (referential integrity enforced with a foreign key constraint), this **short form** is equivalent to the longer form:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT post_id) AS post_ct
FROM   votes;
```

May actually be faster than the `EXISTS` query with *no or few entries* per post.

The query you had works in simpler form, too:

```
SELECT count(*) AS post_ct
FROM  (
    SELECT FROM posts 
    JOIN   votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
    GROUP  BY posts.id
    ) sub;
```

### Benchmark

To verify my claims I ran a benchmark on my test server with limited resources. All in a separate schema:

#### Test setup

Fake a typical post / vote situation:

```
CREATE SCHEMA y;
SET search_path = y;

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id   int PRIMARY KEY
, post text
);

INSERT INTO posts
SELECT g, repeat(chr(g%100 + 32), (random()* 500)::int)  -- random text
FROM   generate_series(1,10000) g;

DELETE FROM posts WHERE random() > 0.9;  -- create ~ 10 % dead tuples

CREATE TABLE votes (
  vote_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, post_id int REFERENCES posts(id)
, up_down bool
);

INSERT INTO votes (post_id, up_down)
SELECT g.* 
FROM  (
   SELECT ((random()* 21)^3)::int + 1111 AS post_id  -- uneven distribution
        , random()::int::bool AS up_down
   FROM   generate_series(1,70000)
   ) g
JOIN   posts p ON p.id = g.post_id;
```

All of the following queries returned the same result (8093 of 9107 posts had votes).
I ran 4 tests with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ant took the best of five on **Postgres 9.1.4** with each of the three queries and appended the resulting **total runtimes**.

1. As is.
2. After ..

   ```
   ANALYZE posts;
   ANALYZE votes;
   ```
3. After ..

   ```
   CREATE INDEX foo on votes(post_id);
   ```
4. After ..

   ```
   VACUUM FULL ANALYZE posts;
   CLUSTER votes using foo;
   ```

#### `count(*) ... WHERE EXISTS`

1. 253 ms
2. 220 ms
3. **85 ms**  -- **winner** (seq scan on posts, index scan on votes, nested loop)
4. 85 ms

#### `count(DISTINCT x)` - long form with join

1. 354 ms
2. 358 ms
3. 373 ms -- (index scan on posts, index scan on votes, merge join)
4. 330 ms

#### `count(DISTINCT x)` - short form without join

1. 164 ms
2. 164 ms
3. 164 ms -- (always seq scan)
4. 142 ms

Best time for **original query** in question:

- 353 ms

For **simplified version**:

- 348 ms

**@wildplasser's query with a CTE** uses the same plan as the long form (index scan on posts, index scan on votes, merge join) plus a little overhead for the CTE. Best time:

- 366 ms

[Index-only scans in the upcoming PostgreSQL 9.2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Index-only_scans) can improve the result for each of these queries, most of all for `EXISTS`.

Related, more detailed benchmark for Postgres 9.5 (actually retrieving distinct rows, not just counting):

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/34715134#34715134)

Comment: What do you mean with "*more portable*"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "more portable" was nonsense, really. Removed that bit, thanks for pointing out. I was under the wrong impression that SQLite would not support `DISTINCT` in aggregate functions. [Turns out, it does](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) - just as all other major RDBMS. As compensation (and because I wanted to clarify that for myself) I elaborate on the performance angle with a benchmark.

Comment: If I read correctly, you missed my CTE-version. It should be equivalent to a subquery, though.

Comment: @wildplasser: Sorry, recreated the scenario (not identical, but close as can be seen from the setup) and added the result for the CTE version. As expected, a CTE doesn't help performance here.

Answer (score 14):

Using `OVER()` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) OVER()
FROM posts 
   INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
GROUP BY posts.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is what worked for my case since I wanted to filter out things with a `HAVING SUM(..) > 5` clause that summed values across rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH uniq AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT posts.id as post_id
        FROM posts
        JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id
        -- GROUP BY not needed anymore
        -- GROUP BY posts.id
        )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM uniq;
```

Answer (score 2):

For followers, I like the OP's inner query method:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all, posts.id as post_id 
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
    GROUP BY posts.id
) as x;
```

Since then you can use HAVING in there as well:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all, posts.id as post_id 
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
    GROUP BY posts.id HAVING count(*) > 1
) as x;
```

Or the equivalent CTE

```
with posts_coalesced as (
     SELECT COUNT(*) as count_all, posts.id as post_id 
        FROM posts 
        INNER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id 
        GROUP BY posts.id )

select count(*) from posts_coalesced;
```