# Select distinct values with count in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1, correlated-subquery

This is a heavily simplified version of an SQL problem I'm dealing with. Let's say I've got a table of all the cities in the world, like this:

```
country city
------------
Canada  Montreal
Cuba    Havanna
China   Beijing
Canada  Victoria
China   Macau
```

I want to count how many cities each country has, so that I would end up with a table as such:

```
country city_count
------------------
Canada  50
Cuba    10
China   200
```

I know that I can get the distinct country values with `SELECT distinct country FROM T1` and I suspect I need to construct a subquery for the city_count column. But my non-SQL brain is just telling me I need to loop through the results...

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807386/group-by-and-count-in-postgresql

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming the only reason for a new row is a unique city

```
select country, count(country) AS City_Count
from table
group by country
```

Comment: Well, that wasn't too difficult. Thank you!

Comment: There are a few aggregate functions like count that come in very handy and are worth knowing to allow you to pull out the key information about the data you have(count brings back the number of occurrences of a value, max gives you the highest value etc) Try this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp