# Counting without duplicates in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, duplicates, distinct

I have a table such as the following

```
**SP     MA     SL   NG**
jame     j001   1    20200715
jame     j001   -1   20200715
jame     j001   1    20200715
pink     p002   12   20200720 
pink     p002   -3   20200720 
pink     p002   12   20200721
```

I'm trying to count record but I have to eliminate duplicates. So, I want a result like

```
 **SP    count
jame     1
pink     2
```

Any suggestions?I could do with some help, please.
Thanks you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24017868/1068246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `count(distinct ...)`?

For example, if you want the count of distinct values in column `ng` for each `sp`:

```
select sp, count(distinct ng) cnt from mytable group by sp
```

If you want to eliminate records that are complete duplicates, another option is `select distinct`  in a subquery first:

```
select sp, count(*) cnt
from (select distinct sp, ma, sl, ng from mytable) t
group by sp
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help.